# ¿Como puedo insertar una variable recibida a lo largo de un mensaje POST en mi base de datos?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, insert

Estoy realizando una conversación con un servidor externo mediante mensajes POST en php y cuando recibo un dato quiero almacenarlo en mi base de datos, ¡como puedo guardarla en la base de datos?
Estoy utilizando el siguiente código:

```
$insert = 'INSERT INTO Clientes (CorreoElectrónico) VALUES $correo';
```

Comment: ¿Y qué error obtienes?

Comment: Cuando tú mandas la info lo haces mediante POST, pero cuando la recibes, la recibes mediante GET por lo que deberías recuperarla con un $_GET['correo'] por ejemplo. Estaría bien que reformularas la pregunta añadiendo tu código y mostrando el mensaje de error para que fuera más sencillo ayudarte :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Varias cosas... supongo que la variable `$correo` está inicializada con el valor de `$_GET['correo']` o la forma en la que le hayas llamado. De la siguiente forma:

```php
$correo = $_GET['correo'];
```

Por otro lado... al tener comillas simples (`'`) en vez de dobles (`"`) vas a tener que hacer una concatenación de la variable:

```php
$insert = 'INSERT INTO Clientes (CorreoElectrónico) VALUES ('.$correo.')';
```

Si quieres hacerlo sin concatenar, utiliza comillas dobles (`"`), esto te permite meter variables dentro del `string` y PHP las concatena automáticamente:

```php
$insert = "INSERT INTO Clientes (CorreoElectrónico) VALUES ($correo)";
```

(En ambos casos he añadido los paréntesis por costumbre y prefiero añadirlos, pero realmente no estoy 100% seguro de que sea necesario)

Por último y a modo de aclaración, `phpMyAdmin` no es un tipo de base de datos, sino un cliente WEB para poder realizar operaciones con una base de datos, seguramente tengas un `MySQL` o un `MariaDB`.